# BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole (pahole) is not available

Tags: compilation, kernel, fedora

Getting this error while compiling the kernel version :5.7-rc4

```
BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole (pahole) is not available
Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1106: vmlinux] Error 1
```

Comment: Next time, try `dnf whatprovides pahole` :-)

Answer (score 87):

Try to install dwarves:

```sh
$ sudo apt install dwarves
```

Comment: This works for Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: I was wondering if this was an april fools joke I wasn't quite sure if there really was such a package.

Comment: Dwarves actual help :)

Comment: Seems like this package was renamed to `pahole` on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: pahole in Debian Bookworm as well: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=pahole

Answer (score 25):

On Fedora, Getting this error while compiling the kernel version :5.7.2(stable)

Try to install

```
$ sudo dnf install dwarves
```

Answer (score 17):

On Arch use
`sudo pacman -S pahole`

Comment: On Void Linux it's also pahole !

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same question and i solved by this method, to enable the powertools:

```
vim /etc/yum.repo.d/CentOS-Linux-PowerTools.repo

enabled=1
```

Comment: Thanks worked like charm on Centos 8, on my server it was  "yum.repos.d"  instead of repo

Answer (score 1):

BPF Type Format can be disabled in config, so pahole won't be needed.

In the kernel config:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=n
```

Comment: This seems to be what the error message suggests. But I don't know how to do this. What/where is kernel config?

Comment: "What/where is kernel config?" Configuration file, you can edit it with some UI like 'make menuconfig' or edit it by hand with some text editor (look for file named .config - dot config). Read tutorial about compiling kernel for your distribution as that are basics stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For Gentoo Linux, this does the trick.

```
emerge -av dev-util/pahole
```

Comment: https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-util/pahole
Breaks kernel builds with BTF enabled. Bug #868762.
Be careful! Some versions are unacceptable for kernel building.

Answer (score 0):

Dwarves it is indeed and as a me too then, on OpenSuse tumbleweed

`$ sudo zypper in dwarves`

Answer (score 0):

Getting same error with the Debian/WSL distro. No newer `dwarves` than `1.10-2.1+b1`.

Apparently this is Debian Stretch (v9), and it needs to be updated to Bullseye (v11). This doc details [how to move from Buster to Bullseye](https://computingforgeeks.com/upgrade-from-debian-10-buster-to-debian-11-bullseye/#:%7E:text=Upgrade%20from%20Debian%2010%20%28Buster%29%20To%20Debian%2011,a%20Minimal%20System%20Upgrade.%20...%20More%20items...%20), i.e. 10 to 11 but it's the same process from 9.

Following the upgrade, we get

```
$  apt list dwarves
Listing... Done
dwarves/stable,now 1.20-1 amd64 [installed]
$ pahole --version
v1.20
```

...and you can go back and run your `make`.